# ajax() does not seem to be working on localhost

Tags: php, jquery

I obtained some code from a friend who was showing me how scrapers work in their most basic forms. Now, the code worked fine on his local environment and when uploaded to live it works fine. However, transferred onto my computer the AJAX call does not seem to work or action. I get no response or error in the console to try and point me in the right direction.

#### Some of the things I have tried

New dev envionment - I was originally running XAMPP and thought this setup could be causing issues so I did a complete reinstall of Apache, PHP(7.3), MySQL...

Disabled firewall

Attempting to enabling CORS with `<?php header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");` at the top of each PHP file

Using `get()` instead of `ajax()`

I can't think of other off the top of my head but I have done a fair bit of trawling overnight and do not seem to have come across the solution. I assume that it is an issue with my local setup, because if the files are uploaded, they will work. If I browse to `localhost/footy-api.php` it displays the JSON (with errors, but thats down to incorrect targeting).

Does anyone have any potential solutions to this?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Footy Theft</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="jsearch.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/8af6c2989d.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
  <script type="text/javascript">

    function SHOW(data) {
        var HTML = '<hr/><table class="w3-table-all w3-hoverable"><tr><th>League</th><th>Home Boys</th><th>socre/time</th><th>visitors</th></tr>';
        for(var ff=0; ff<data.length; ff++) {
            //console.log(JSON.stringify(data[ff]));
            var ROW = '<tr><td>'+ data[ff].league +'</td>';
            ROW += '<td>'+ data[ff].team1 +'</td>';
            ROW += '<td>'+ data[ff].info +'</td>';
            ROW += '<td>'+ data[ff].team2 +'</td></tr>';
            HTML += ROW;
        };
        HTML += '</table>';
        $('#RESULTS').html(HTML); 
    };
    function GO() {
      $('#DEBUG').text(" Please wait, searching all the internets... ");
      $.ajax({ url: "footy-api.php" })
      .done(function(data) {
        alert("ok");
        $('#DEBUG').text(""); //JSON.stringify(data));
        SHOW(data); 
      });
    };
    $(document).ready(function () {
        GO();
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="w3-bar w3-black">
    <span class="w3-bar-item w3-text-pink">Sweaty Sock Fights</span>
    <a href="#" onclick="GO()" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-green"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
  </div>
  <div id="DEBUG" class="w3-container w3-large"></div>
  <div id="RESULTS" class="w3-container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<?php
  header('Content-Type: text/json'); 
  require('utils-php.php');
  function BBC(&$BUILD) {
      //$url="URL-TO-GRAB";
      //$ch = curl_init();
      //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
      //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
      //curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
      //$GRAB = curl_exec($ch);
      //curl_close($ch);
      $GRAB = file_get_contents('https://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/highland-league/scores-fixtures');
      $HITS = explode( '<article ', $GRAB );
      for( $hh=1; $hh<count($HITS); $hh++ ) {
        $INFO = null;
        $INFO->site = "BBC";
        $INFO->game = $hh."/".(count($HITS)-1);
        $INFO->league = TextBetween($HITS[$hh], '$0', '.');
        $INFO->team1 = TextBetween($HITS[$hh], '<abbr title="', '"');
        $INFO->team2 = TextBetween(TextAfter($HITS[$hh], 'fixture__team--time-away'), '<abbr title="', '"');
        $INFO->info = TextAfter(TextBetween($HITS[$hh], 'fixture__number--time', '</span>'), '>');
        if(strlen($INFO->league)>1) array_push($BUILD, $INFO);
      }
  }
  $ALL = array();
  BBC($ALL);
  $FINAL = str_replace("\/", "/", json_encode($ALL));
  $FINAL = str_replace("\'", "'", $FINAL);
  echo $FINAL;
?>
```

Comment: What do you see in the network tab?

Comment: To start with, you can try chaining `.fail()` handler after `$.ajax(...).done(...).fail(...` and `console.log` the error to know what is failing.

Comment: @SLaks a good point, I should have checked that long ago. 200 response and all seems fine. .fail() did show an error `Creating default object from empty value in` . Turns out it was the way the object was being initilized. I'll post the solution now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After using the above debuggin methods I found the file was returning 200 and seemed to be found correctly. Running `.fail()` and logging it returned an error `Creating default object from empty value in...`

After speaking with my colleague, it turns out the reason for this is the way a new object was being initialized.

Changed:
`$INFO = null;`

to:
`$INFO = new stdClass();`

All working fine.

Comment: Thanks very much for updating us as to the solution you found. Well done. Good info for me, personally, as well as I was puzzling over what was going on.